# Узнать, запущена ли игра в редакторе или нет

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, unity3d-editor

Я использую атрибут ExecuteInEditMode, функцию которую мне нужно т.е.

```
$if UNITY_EDITOR
public void SetAllItem()
{
Debug.Log("Test");
}
$endif
```

и вызываю в апдейте

```
private void Update()
{
$if UNITY_EDITOR
SetAllItem();
$endif
}
```

да я понимаю что она как-то по другом должна вызываться (контекстное меню не подходит) но я не знаю как и вызываю так, но как можно сделать так что бы функция вызывалась только если игра не запущена, т.е. что бы только в моде редактирования.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример кода если игра была запущена из эдитора:

> Returns true if the game is being run from the Unity editor; false if run from any deployment target.

Возвращает true, если запущен редактор Unity; false в остальных случаях

```
using UnityEngine;

class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        if (Application.isEditor)
        {
            print("We are running this from inside of the editor!");
        }
    }
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-isEditor.html

---

Если игра запущена в принципе:

```
using UnityEngine;

class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        if (Application.isPlaying)
        {
            print("In player or playmode");
        }
    }
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-isPlaying.html

---

Так же возможно будет полезным атрибут `[ExecuteInEditMode]`

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class PrintAwake : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("Editor causes this Awake");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("Editor causes this Update");
    }
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html

Answer (score 1):

[`isEditor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-isEditor.html) и [`isPlaying`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication-isPlaying.html), вероятно, то, что вам надо.